# Creating Ruby Gem to insert HTML/JavaScript into main Application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I create a [Rails Engine](https://github.com/Sparkmasterflex/marxjs-rails) to easily include a JavaScript plugin for rails apps. The problem is that this plugin is really only for development and when pushing an app to production the developer needs to remove the `require marx` in the javascript manifest file and then the actual call in the JavaScript.

What I'm hoping to do is allow the developer to just add this to the *Gemfile* with `gem 'marxjs-rails', group: :development` and setup some configurations in *config/application.rb* or *config/environments/development.rb* for the plugin settings.

The gem should then insert html to the parent application:

```
<script src='marx.js'></script>
<script>
  var marx = new Marx()
</script>
```

I've been playing around with a helper method to insert the html but I can't get it to insert it as html. Rails continues to escape the HTML. Though I don't really like this path any how.

I've been looking through the *jasmine-gem* and *rack-olark* as examples, but can't quite get anything to work.

**UPDATE**

This is not the solution I'm really looking for but this may help others and is what I'm using till I can track down a better way to do this. You can view the whole code [here](https://github.com/Sparkmasterflex/marxjs-rails/tree/auto-insert-js) but I'll give you the highlights:

```
# lib/marxjs/rails.rb
require "marxjs/rails/version"
require "marxjs/view_helpers"

module Marxjs
  module Rails
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
      initializer "marxjs.view_helpers" do
        ActionView::Base.send :include, ViewHelpers
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and the view helpers:

```
# lib/marxjs/view_helpers.rb
require 'erb'

module Marxjs
  module ViewHelpers
    include ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper

    def render_marxjs options={}, dev_only=true
      if dev_only == false || (dev_only && ::Rails.env.development?)
        binding.local_variable_set(:options, options.to_json)
        template_file = ::File.read(::File.expand_path('../templates/marxjs.erb', __FILE__))
        raw ERB.new(template_file).result(binding)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

biggest thing to take away here is the `include ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper` and also the `require 'erb'`
This gives us the ability to load a template *erb* file and use `ERB.new` to render it and use `raw` to keep rails from escaping the html. I also bound an *options* variable to the `binding` object to send it to the template.

```
<script src="assets/marx.js"></script>
<script>
  var marx = new Marx(<%= options %>);
</script>
```

and finally in my main rails application I call `render_marxjs(controls: 'toggle-all')` in the *application.html.haml* (or .erb if you like)

Again I'm still looking for someone to help me handle this without a view helper method and also to be able to set some configurations via an environment file, but I hope this may help some...

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this without creating an engine.

- Add a file called `lib/marxjs/script_inserter.rb`

  ```
  module Marxjs
    module ScriptInserter
      BODY_TAG = %r{</body>}

      JS_SCRIPT = %q{
        <script src='marx.js'></script>
        <script>
          var marx = new Marx()
        </script>    
      }

      def insert_marxjs
        if (
          response.content_type == 'text/html' &&
          response.body.match(BODY_TAG)
        )
          response.body = response.body.gsub(BODY_TAG, JS_SCRIPT + '\\0')
        end      
      end
    end
  end
  ```
- Add `lib/marxjs/railtie.rb`

  ```
  module Marxjs
    class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
      initializer "marxjs-rails" do |app|
        ActionController::Base.send :include Marxjs::ScriptInserter      
        ActionController::Base.after_filter :insert_marxjs
      end
    end
  end
  ```
- Update `lib/marxjs/rails.rb`

  ```
  require "marxjs/rails/version"
  require "marxjs/view_helpers"
  require "marxjs/script_inserter"

  # move rails initialization code to railtie.rb
  ```
- Add the gem to `Gemfile`

  ```
  gem 'marxjs-rails', group: :development
  ```

Comment: Thank you Harish. This looks very promising. I'll give it a try

Comment: It's better to do the same thing with rack middleware, it's more universal and can be used in any ruby framework that uses rack (almost 100% of the frameworks).

Answer (score 2):

The [rack-mini-profiler gem](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler) does something like this, where it adds UI elements to your screen but only in development (by default).  See https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/lib/mini_profiler_rails/railtie.rb

Answer (score 1):

For me the best way is to add the engine on all environments, but require it separately on `application.html.haml`:

```
= javascript_include_tag "mark.js" if Rails.env.development?
```

Be sure to add it to your config/application.rb as well to be compiled:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( mark.js )
```

Comment: Thanks pedro, though I was looking for a way that the developer to not have to do anything but include it in their gemfile to be up and running.  Then if they want further control, they would set some configs in the _application.rb_ or something

Comment: I don't think you can. There's no way of telling which layout you'd want it to be included to.